# Lower deployment target in Xcode11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11, uiscenedelegate

How do I safely lower the deployment target when creating a new project in Xcode11?

I create a single view app -> Language - Swift, User Interface - Storyboard.
Xcode creates a SceneDelegate.swift along with a storyboard file which I thought was used only for SwiftUI, and sets the deployment target to iOS 13.

- When lowering the deployment target Xcode complains about "'UIScene' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer" and a lot of other stuff in the SceneDelegate.swift.
- I deleted this file and tried to run, got this error: "The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file"
- Added `var window: UIWindow?` to the AppDelegate.swift, but the error is still present after clean and build.

Comment: For anyone looking for an updated "Single View App" Xcode template that supports iOS 12 and 13 as well as supporting either a storyboard or an all-code user interface, see https://github.com/rmaddy/XcodeTemplates.